# Finding path from A to B using a minimal spanning tree - C/C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

Say we find a minimal spanning tree. Now, we just need a path from A to Z in the MST. How can we do this in O(n^2) time?

We start at root A. then we look at all edges in the tree of the form Ax (where x is any vertex).

Then, say we find: AB, AC, AD, etc...
Then for each one, we look for edges of form: Bx, Cx, Dx...this is clearly not O(n^2).

So what is a better / efficient way to find path A -> Z given a MST?

Thanks

Comment: edge weights are distances between points, so no they are not necessarily integers.

Comment: How would a DFS work? We create a DFS from the MST?

Comment: @user809240, why O(n^2) is a goal? It would be hard to that with MST for more than O(n) (as it has n-1 edge for n points)

Answer (score 5):

[Depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) will be sufficient, it is in the worst case *O(|V| + |E|)*. The fact that your input is a MST means that you don't have to worry about any loop detection, as you would have in a general graph.

Comment: It should also be noted that in a MST `|E|` is at most `|V|` and not `|V|^2` as in a general graph, so the algorithm will be `O(|V|)`. Way faster than the goal of `O(|V|^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Look up [Minimum Spanning Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) and you will find that it is a minimum subgraph that connects all the vertices together. That means that every edge will be used at **most** once. You can just use either a DFS or BFS to find the desired path, without the need to check for cycles since you already have the MST.

Answer (score 0):

During MST creation you could fill parent[], so after that using simple backtracking you would be able to find path without DFS.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, Prim's algorithm for finding an MST is really just Dijkstra's in disguise. So the MST already gives you the shortest path if you find one (as stated above, think DFS).